# Can i store Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row in a variable?

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am wondering if I can store this function as a variable. As I am working with vlookups and want my code to be adaptable if rows are added/removed from the source worksheet.

For example, instead of the "2402" being hard coded into this vlookup. Can I place a variable there that can reference the row count formula?

```
Cells(xlRow, 149).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(EG" & xlRow & "," & FILEPATH & "RDWY'!$A$2:$N$2402,6,0)"
```

I know I can just do the below, but it could result in the code becoming very long and even more confusing for all my vlookups.

```
Cells(xlRow, 149).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(EG" & xlRow & "," & FILEPATH & "RDWY'!$A$2:$N$" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row & ",6,0)"
```

What I would like to do is have say, " "RDWY'!$A$2:$N$" & rowcount & ",6,0)". Is this possible? If not, why is it not possible?

EDIT: I have set my rowCount variable to `rowCount = blanketWB.Sheets("RDWY").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and it worked!

Thanks for confirming the syntax everyone. I should have just tried it before posting. At least it's here now in case anyone else has a similar question in the future.

Some of my vlookups will have to be hard coded numbers though because there are certain weight breaks in some of the source worksheets. Where just by getting the row count from the last row wouldn't help. However, I can apply this to the majority.

Comment: Did you try it?  If so what error did you get?  There is nothing wrong with the syntax as you have shown.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: But in this specific case there is no reason to limit the lookup range.  `$A:$N` will perform just a quickly as `$A$2:$N$2402`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add your "formula" inside a varible, just like this:

```
Dim formula as String
formula = "=VLOOKUP(EG" & xlRow & "," & FILEPATH & "RDWY'!$A$2:$N$2402,6,0)"
```

and then you can use it inside your code:

```
Cells(xlRow, 149).Formula = formula
```

Comment: It's okay now? sorry i'm not used to vba